# React Native - Stack Navigator Check from which screen has the new panel been opened

Tags: reactjs, routes, screen, native, navigator

I am using [Stack Navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html) for navigating between screens. I have a Info screen which can be accessed from two other different screens in my app. Depending from which screen I have tried to access my Info panel, different text should be displayed on it. How can I check which was the screen before the current one(the info screen)?

I tried playing with `this.props.navigation.state.routeName`. However, it would only return the name of the current panel, not the one before. Is there any way I can check the previous one or at least get its' name?

Comment: Store the current panel name for later usage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass the name of the screen in `params` from which you're navigating to `info` screen

```
let { routeName } = this.props.navigation.state;

this.props.navigation.navigate('info', {
  lastScreen: routeName 
});
```

and get the name of prev. screen in `info` screen like so

```
const { lastScreen } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
....
```

I hope it helps.

Read more about [Passing parameters to routes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params.html)